# Why did OnDataPointListener stoped being called?

Tags: google-api, google-fit

My App has being working for a few months now. 
3 days ago is, it stoped working well. I realized it stoped reaching onDataPoint().
I did not change a thing.
What can cause it?

I use

```
Fitness.SensorsApi.add( mGoogleApiClient, 
    new SensorRequest.Builder().
    setDataType(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)....
```

When I debug, I see it does not reach

```
@Override
public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because google fit api stopped returning location samples unless the same app writes them. See the release notes for November 19, 2018 from the below link

https://developers.google.com/fit/android/releases

Comment: Thank you. 
So in what way do I get Locations now?